# How to create private method/property in Ember.Object?

Tags: ember.js

We can create Em.Object like this:

```js
var foo = Em.Object.create({
   somevar : '123'
});
```

and then use it:

```js
foo.get('somevar');
```

but how to create a private property or method in Em.Object which would be accessable from the object but wouldnt be ourside?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not possible, since Ember.js does not provide any encapsulation mechanisms.

However, you can simply use some convention for private members. For example, prefix them with `_` sign.

Comment: got it, thanx! interesting, are ember's authors interesting in commit with such kind of functionality

Comment: For visitors coming here after five years, please be aware that this (accepted) answer is wrong.

Answer (score 8):

There is indeed a way to have private variables in Ember objects, as follows:

```
MyObject = Ember.Object.extend({
  init: function() {
    // private variable
    var a = 1;

    // methods to get, set, or otherwise accesss the private variables
    this.getA = function() {return a;};
    this.setA = function(val) {a = val;}

    // don't forget this!
    this._super(...arguments);
  }
});
```

now try

```
o1 = MyObject.create()
o2 = MyObject.create()
o1.setA(42);
o2.getA(); //1
```

In other words, you have to declare the private variables, AND any getters, setters, or other routines that want to use them, in the `init` hook. Of course, this means that those getters/setters will be present on each instance of the class, rather than in its prototype. That's slightly inefficient, but the same holds for any approach to private variables for classes in JavaScript.

It is conceivable that Ember could introduce a new `private: {}` hash on objects, but then Ember would need a lot of machinery to handle finding and controlling access to private variables across class hierarchies. It would be equivalent to redesigning or extending the language itself, which is not part of the Ember mission.

Meanwhile, the above approach works fine if the number of private instance variables is limited and the number of routines that need to access them is small. So the accepted answer that says this is impossible is, well, wrong.

Comment: This should be voted up as it is the correct answer, and still relevant as of Ember 2.0

Answer (score 0):

You could use a closure:

```
(function() {
    var somePrivateProperty = 'xyz';

    MyObject = Em.Object.extend({
        someComputedProperty: function() {
            return 'somePrivateProperty = ' + somePrivateProperty;
        }).property()
    })
})();
```

Comment: yeah, but MyObject.get('someComputedProperty') can be used almost from anywhere

Comment: THis will not work, because `somePrivateProperty` will be shared among all instances.

Answer (score 0):

Is possible with a little trick:

```
var obj = Em.Em.Object.create(
    new function(){
        var privateVar = "this is private";
        this.getPrivateVar = function(){
            return privateVar ;
        }
    },
    {
        emberVar: "Ember var",
        emberMethod : function(){
            return this.getPrivateVar();
        },
        emberMethod1 : function(){
            return privateVar ;
        },
        emberBinding : 'emberVar'
    }
)
```

now if U try to get `private` var

```
obj.privateVar 
> unknown

obj.getPrivateVar()
> "this is private"

obj.emberMethod()
> "this is private"
```

The only problem is that:

```
obj.emberMethod1()
> unknown
```

Comment: This doesn't work, because `privateVar` will be shared among all instances.